# c# windows phone 8 facebook group integration

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8

I'd like to know if its possible to get a list of items from a facebook group I have set up for the local community, would it be possible to also let the users post on the facebook group wall via a windows phone 8 app?

I have searched online but haven't came across anything which leads me to presume that groups are exempt from facebook sdk for windows phone

Comment: Of course you can. Did you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried posting to groups, but ive used the windows phone facebook sdk to post on a users timeline, what I need is the ability to let people at the very least view all posts in a group and if I can let them post items to the group via the app.